# Can't include script angular2 index.html (not found)

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Aerosmith Messenger</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" 
rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/spinner.css" />

  <!--<script src="src/scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js">

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <am-root>
    <div class="spinner">
      <div class="double-bounce1"></div>
      <div class="double-bounce2"></div>
    </div>
  </am-root>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to include jquery script. And it does not work when i include it like this (commented line). Help me resolve this issue because i need to include some other scripts.
By "does not work" i mean all the time that commented script is not found in console of a browser.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a technical description of the problem. Did you look in your developer tools of the browser?

Comment: You seem to be missing some core knowledge of angular if this is your root html file.

Comment: By "does not work" i mean all the time that commented script is not found in console of a browser.

Comment: Latest version of angular-cli(angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.19-3) provides an assets folder under src directory. You just need to add src property of an image tag like this:   <img src="./assets/logo.png">

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install --save jquery
npm install -D @types/jquery
```

In your `app.module.ts` file :

```
import $ from 'jquery';

// Works :
$('#foo').value();
```

Comment: Latest version of angular-cli(angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.19-3) provides an assets folder under src directory. You just need to add src property of an image tag like this:   <img src="./assets/logo.png">

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the way you call it. Maybe you are calling it from a worng path or the js file is not a good prebuilt. Go to the browser and inspect to see if it can find the js file.

Comment: Latest version of angular-cli(angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.19-3) provides an assets folder under src directory. You just need to add src property of an image tag like this:   <img src="./assets/logo.png">

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your jQuery JavaScript file is located in your project at `src/scripts/`

Comment: Latest version of angular-cli(angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.19-3) provides an assets folder under src directory. You just need to add src property of an image tag like this:   <img src="./assets/logo.png">